# CascadeType vs FetchType

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascading, fetching-strategy

I would like to now what is the difference between CascadeType and FetchType in Hibernate?

They seem very similar but I guess they are not interchangeable, right?
When to use them? Can they be used both at the same time?

Comment: does my answer help you? if so please accept/vote it.

Comment: @jarosik if so please accept/vote it.

Comment: The two are very different. Refer to page 89 for FetchType. For Cascading refer to section 3.2 (page 80) http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1508489100_12b9c9f1827b7c7734914284a141af08

Answer (score 11):

These are 2 different things:

The `CascadeType` in Hib. could be `REFRESH`, `MERGE`, ..., `ALL` you put it under the related entity and **it determines the behavior of the related entity** if the current entity is: refreshed, updated, deleted, e.t.c.. So whenever you entity is affected the `CascadeType` tells if the related entity should be affected as well.

The `FetchType` could be only of 2: `EAGER` and `LAZY`. This one you as well put under the related entity and **it determines whether the related entity should be initialized right away when the current entity is initialized** (`EAGER`) **or only on demand** (`LAZY`).

Comment: Specifically this applies not only to Hibernate but JPA in general (As per JSR338). Doc: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1508489100_12b9c9f1827b7c7734914284a141af08

Answer (score 3):

[Cascading](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) is used for propagating [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/) from a Parent entity to a Child.

[Fetching](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/) is used for loading associated entities and you can have:

- global fetch policies (defined through entity mapping)
- query-time fetch policy (using the HQL/JPQL FETCH directive)

Comment: Hi @Vlad. What happens if i set `CascadeType` to `MERGE` and `REFRESH` and `FetchType` to `LAZY`? I tested it and i see that the hibernate ignores the `FetchType.LAZY' and fetches all children; is it correct?

Comment: @ArashNo, it's not correct. Fetching and cascading have nothing in common.

Answer (score 1):

Both are different configurations, you can relate it with simple SQL.

Cascade tells you what happens when one entity gets updated ( on delete cascade in sql)

Fetch tells how the query is going to be executed ( join, lazy ...)

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference between the two of them.

- **CascadeType** is a property used to define cascading in arelationship between a parent and a child.
- **FetchType** is a property used to define fetching strategies which are used to optimize the Hibernate generated select statement, so that it
  can be as efficient as possible.

You can find more about them in:

1. **[Hibernate – fetching strategies examples](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/)**
2. **[Hibernate JPA Cascade Types](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/25/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/)**